# How to use Graphics.TranslateTransform temporarily

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use `Graphics.TranslateTransform` to offset the content of a button but only the content, not anything drawn later such as a focus rectangle.

```
    protected override void DrawContent(ObjectInfoArgs e)
    {
        var isPressed = (e.State & ObjectState.Pressed) == ObjectState.Pressed;

        if (isPressed) e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(2, 2);
        base.DrawContent(e);
        if (isPressed) e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-2, -2);
        //if (isPressed) e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
    }
```

I do not create the e.Graphics in the sample so I cannot have any idea whether other Transforms are already present and I want to keep preserve anything already present.

Is it acceptable to just 'reverse' the one I added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's acceptible with only one transform and such a small block of code.

You could also use:

```
GraphicsState state = e.Graphics.Save();
...
e.Graphics.Restore(state);
```